# Cannot modify a list value with shared dictionary in multiprocessing python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

This code works perfectly and prints {'hello': 2}, as expected.

```
def func():
    def f(d):
        d['hello'] += 1

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        manager = Manager()
        d = manager.dict()
        d['hello'] = 0
        p1 = Process(target=f, args=(d,))
        p2 = Process(target=f, args=(d,))
        p1.start()
        p2.start()
        p1.join()
        p2.join()

        print(d)
func()
```

However, if I instead make the value of 'hello' a list [0,0], and then += 1 to the 0th index of the value, it does not work. {'hello': [0, 0]} is returned instead of the expected {'hello': [2, 0]}

```
def func2():
    def f(d):
        d['hello'][0] += 1

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        manager = Manager()
        d = manager.dict()
        d['hello'] = [0,0]
        p1 = Process(target=f, args=(d,))
        p2 = Process(target=f, args=(d,))
        p1.start()
        p2.start()
        p1.join()
        p2.join()

        print(d)

func2()
```

Why is this happening and how can I allow f() to properly add to the 0th index of the list value?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is described in official docs:

> Modifications to mutable values or items in dict and list proxies will not be propagated through the manager, because the proxy has no way of knowing when its values or items are modified. To modify such an item, you can re-assign the modified object to the container proxy:

```
 # create a list proxy and append a mutable object (a dictionary)
lproxy = manager.list()
lproxy.append({})
# now mutate the dictionary
d = lproxy[0]
d['a'] = 1
d['b'] = 2
# at this point, the changes to d are not yet synced, but by
# reassigning the dictionary, the proxy is notified of the change
lproxy[0] = d
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, it works when I modify it like this:

```
def func2():
    def f(d):
        d['hello'] = [d['hello'][0] + 1, d['hello'][1]]

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        manager = Manager()
        d = manager.dict()
        d['hello'] = [0,0]
        p1 = Process(target=f, args=(d,))
        p2 = Process(target=f, args=(d,))
        p1.start()
        p2.start()
        p1.join()
        p2.join()

        print(d)
func2()
```